# Angular 2 - display value from an event listener function in the view via class property

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, angular, event-listener

I'm working with ionic 2/angular 2 and google maps.

i have a class

```
    import {Page, Platform} from  'ionic-angular';
    import {Geolocation} from 'ionic-native';
    import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

    @Page({
        templateUrl: 'build/pages/mapPage/mapPage.html',
    })

    export class MapPage {

        date: String = new Date().toISOString();
        address: any = 'Pick a place';

        constructor(private platform: Platform, private http: Http) {
            this.platform = platform;
            this.initializeMap();
        }


        initializeMap() {
        let HTTPP = this.http;
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            var myLatLng = {};
            var image = 'custom/img/map-marker-small.png';

            Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(pos => {
                myLatLng = { lat: pos.coords.latitude, lng: pos.coords.longitude };                 
            })
                .then(() => {
                    var minZoomLevel = 17;

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                        zoom: minZoomLevel,
                        center: myLatLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });
                });

             var getAddress = function (lat, lng) {
                    let mapUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&key=XXXXXXXXX';  // URL to web API
                    let address = "";

                    return HTTPP.get(mapUrl)
                        .toPromise()
                        .then(data => {
                            let data2 = data.json().results;                                
                            data2[0]['address_components'].forEach(add => {
                                address += add.long_name + ", ";
                            });
                            return address;
                        });
                }

                marker.addListener('dragend', function (event) {
                    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
                    var lng = event.latLng.lng();

                    console.log("lat: " + lat + ", lng: " + lng);

                    getAddress(lat, lng)
                    .then(function(address){
                        console.log(address); //WORKS CORRECTLY
                        //but can't access `this` here. 
                        //this.address = address //THIS IS WHAT I WANT 
                        return address;
                    })

                });
           });
         }
      }
```

What i want to accomplish is to get the address of the marker that has been dragged to a coordinate and display it to the user in the front end

```
 <ion-navbar *navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Map Example
  </ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="home">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 60%"></div>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="DDD MMM DD, h:mm A" pickerFormat="DDD DD MMM h mm A" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>

  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
   {{address}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

When the marker is dragged i have successfully gotten the coordinates and have successfully gotten the address string. But the `this` operator is not available in the event listener function for the dragend event of the marker.

How can i equate `this.address` to my address that i got inside the event listener?

I have tried to make a general refrence to `this` by doing `let self = this;` and then using `self.address = address` inside the function in hopes that it would reflect in the view. but it didn't work.

All i want to do is to display the address in the front end when the user drags the marker to a new location.

Any help would be appreciated thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
function (event) {
```

to

```
(event) => {
```

to retain the scope of `this`

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Thanks :) was able to access `this` inside the function. Can't seem to get it to show on the view tho even after doing `this.address = address`

Comment: @RaymondAtivie Because `this` inside of `then` callback is also lost (not a component instance).

Answer (score 2):

There are two places where you lose context: `dragend` event handler and `then` callback function. Use arrow function for both of them, this will preserve lexical scope:

```
marker.addListener('dragend', event => {

  var lat = event.latLng.lat();
  var lng = event.latLng.lng();

  getAddress(lat, lng)
    .then(address => this.address = address);

});
```